# Failure connecting to MySQL on localhost

Tags: c#, mysql, xampp

So I'm trying to add a new record to a SQL Database. The MySQL database server is running on XAMPP, and I've configured the username to be root and the password to be test. I've tried both 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1' as the server addresses but they both don't work.
This is using:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Gtk;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

When the button is clicked, it catches the exception and displays an error message, but I can't figure out why the connection to the server fails.

```
protected void OnAddItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection connection;
    string server = "localhost";
    string database = "shop";
    string uid = "root";
    string password = "test";
    string connectionString;
    connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
    database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

    connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO items (ItemName,Price,PriceVAT) values(@ItemName,@Price,@PriceVAT", connection);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemName", nameEntry.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price", priceEntry.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PriceVAT", "1");
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog(null, DialogFlags.Modal, MessageType.Info, ButtonsType.Ok, "Data entered successfully.");
            md.Run();
            md.Destroy();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog(null, DialogFlags.Modal, MessageType.Info, ButtonsType.Ok, "Database connection failed.");
            md.Run();
            md.Destroy();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog(null, DialogFlags.Modal, MessageType.Info, ButtonsType.Ok, "Error occurred, please try again later");
        md.Run();
        md.Destroy();
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: `displays an error message` what was that message

Comment: I'm not sure, if I run it without the try-catch, the GUI just closes when i press the button without any exception.

Answer (score 0):

If db user and password correct then ake your connection string like

```
connectionString  = @"server=" + server  + ";userid=" + uid + ";password="
                       + password + ";database=" + database;
```

and if your mysql port is not default like `3306`then you can specify your custom port number too like

```
connectionString = @"server=" + server + ";port=" + port + ";userid=" + uid  + ";password="
                       + password  + ";database=" + database;
```

Comment: I've changed the connectionString as you suggested, and checked on XAMPP, the port is 3306. Still doesn't work :(

Comment: I changed the "Error ccurred, please try again later" to ex.Message and it just returns CreateSemaphore, is this the exception? Sorry I'm quite new to C#